# Write REAL array to CSV string, but compile fails on assumed-size arrays

Tags: csv, fortran, format

I'm trying to write a function to convert a REAL array to a CSV string in a character variable using the WRITE statement with a FMT for floating point values.

The FMT string and approach are something I've used before without a problem.  Even in this program, using the same code within the main program (rather than within a MODULE) compiles without a hitch and runs like a charm.

The code (updated) is as follows:

```
      ! #############################################
      module generic

      implicit none

      contains

      function writecsv(realvars)

      character*10000 writecsv
      real*4, intent(in) :: realvars(*)
      character*15 csvfmt

      csvfmt='(*(F0.3,:",",))'
      writecsv=""

      write(writecsv,csvfmt) realvars

      end function writecsv

      end module generic

      ! #############################################
      program main

      use generic

      implicit none

      real*4 var(5)

      var =(/123.123,345.345,567.567,789.789,100.001/)

      write (*,*) trim(writecsv(var))

      end program main

      ! #############################################
```

Currently compiling as follows:

```
gfortran -ffree-form -static -o .\fmt_error.EXE .\fmt_error.for
```

And I get the following error:

```
.\fmt_error.for:16:28:

       write(writecsv,csvfmt) realvars
                            1
Error: The upper bound in the last dimension must appear in the reference to the assumed size array 'realvars' at (1)
.\fmt_error.for:16:37:

       write(writecsv,csvfmt) realvars
                                     1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot be a full reference to an assumed-size array
.\fmt_error.for:24:10:

       use generic
          1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'generic.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Where previously I was having an issue with the FMT string specifically, now I'm getting more general errors.  I can't repeat the previous issue having used a workaround to get the software working in the interim.  Thus, it was probably just me.

The errors now suggest I'm using assumed-size arrays and assumed lengths in the write FMT, and that the two are incompatible.  At least my initial hunch was in the ballpark!

If this is indeed the case please do let me know and I'll delete the post, as it's then more a an issue of understanding of the language rather than with the code.

Having an assumed-size CSV writer would be very handy though!

Comment: Please post a real [mcve]. Your function cannot be compiled. If I fix it so that it compiles, it does not show the error. Post the actual code.

Comment: The code that you have posted is not the code that generates the error you claim to have gotten.  The code is not valid Fortran.

Comment: Thanks gents, will update as soon as I can.  Patience much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, indeed a duplicate.  Initially I couldn't pin down the problem but the errors reported with the updated code do positively identify the problem.